# ValidateAntiForgeryToken in windows authentication

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, antiforgerytoken

Our application uses AngularJS and consumed Web API in the backend. This is only internal application and authentication used is 'Windows' mode only. We are using custom authorization(role-base) to limit the access/execution of the application web api methods.

My question is do we need to add ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute for those web api action with HttpPost and HttpPut attribute? I never use this ValidateAntiForgeryToken before as I was only involved in internal web application (local intranet only). Please guide me **when**/**how** to use ValidateAntiForgeryToken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValidateAntiForgeryToken` protects your users from malicious web apps that send a POST request to your web app unbeknownst to your user, known as [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). Still the request would succeed since it's coming from your user who actually has permission to do so.
This is irrespective of the actual authentication mechanism, and is in fact a higher risk for automatic single-sing on that you have with Windows authentication.

If your internal web app is worth the effort, a targeted attack could trick your users to visit the attacker's web site that in turn sends the POST request to your web app.

My take is that you should use ValidateAntiForgeryToken even in this situation as a defense-in-depth measure.